# How to Securely Use SecretStrage in VScode Extension

Tags: javascript, typescript, security, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am trying to create an extension to VSCode and am thinking of using SecretStrage to hold secret values.

In the vscode-extension-samples repository, SecretStrage is used as follows

```
export class AzureDevOpsAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider, Disposable {
  private static secretKey = 'AzureDevOpsPAT';
  ...
  
  private cacheTokenFromStorage() {
    this.currentToken = this.secretStorage.get(AzureDevOpsAuthenticationProvider.secretKey) as Promise<string | undefined>;
    return this.currentToken;
  }
}
```

However, I fear that this would allow access to the secret value when the implementation is seen and the secretkey is known.

As long as I don't publish my implementation on github, etc., will it ever be known if I use a fixed value for secretkey?

Or should I implement it more securely? Is there a good solution for that?